# PHP/Regex - Grab everything between { and }?

Tags: php, regex

I have some text strings like this

> {hello|hi}{there|you}

I want to count the instances of {..anything..}, so in the example above, I would want to return:

> hello|hi
>   there|you

in the matches array created by `preg_match_all()`

Right now my code looks like:

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $text,$text_pieces);
```

And $text_pieces contains:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => {hello|hi} [1] => {there|you} ) [1] => Array ( [0] => hello|hi [1] => there|you ) )
```

All I need is this:

```
[0] => hello|hi [1] => there|you
```

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match_all` cannot omit the full text matches, only subpattern matches, therefore the only solution is to set `$text_pieces` to `$text_pieces[1]` after the function call:

```
if(preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $text,$text_pieces))
{
    $text_pieces = $text_pieces[1];
}
```

Comment: +! But you should probably add some error checking code to avoid a php runtime error when there are no matches, e.g. when `preg_match_all()` returns 0.